# The following code iterates and output banana, how can i change it to reverse the output?

Tags: python, string, while-loop

I want to modify this code in such a the output is a reverse of the string *"banana"*

```
index = 0
fruit = "banana"
while index < len(fruit):
    letter = fruit[index]
    print (letter)
    index = index + 1
```

The current **output**

```
b
a
n
a
n
a
```

Expected **output**

```
a
n
a
n
a
b
```

Comment: Do you understand what `letter = fruit[index]` does? How would you modify your code to select the _last letter_ of `fruit` first, and then go to the previous letter? If you don't, I suggest you redo a tutorial on string indexing.

Comment: thanks. I figured it out. @PranavHosangadi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach. In Python -1 means last position, so the len of the word (negative) is the first position of your slice.

Because Python range is not inclusive, you have to add a -1 to this scenario. Otherwise it it will print "anana".

Finally, we want to go from -1 to -6, so the increment must be -1.

```
word = "banana"
start = -1
end = (len(word) * -1) - 1
increment = -1

print(word[start:end:increment])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
fruit = "banana"
index = len(fruit)
while index > 0:
    letter = fruit[index-1]
    print (letter)
    index = index -1
```

But I strongly recommend you to check and understand how string indexing works.

Answer (score 0):

```
fruit = "banana"
rev_fruit = fruit[::-1]
print(rev_fruit)
```

#output: ananab